# cannot copy string to a static struct member using strcpy

Tags: c++

I am trying to access a static struct member and set it using string copy in c++11 but I dont see the issue with the way I am doing it.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

struct x {
   char a;
   static char s[20];
};

char x::s[20] = "instance 1";

std::strcpy(x::s,"instance 1");

struct x A = {'A'};

struct x B = {'B'};
```

I get the following error

```
 main.cpp:18:12: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 std::strcpy(x::s,"instance 1");
            ^
```

Could someone please explain ?

Comment: Have you `#include <cstring>`?

Comment: Why not `std::string` instead of C-style fixed-length character buffers?

Comment: yes. Sorry about that. I edited my question

Comment: What's the intent of `static char s`?

Comment: Where is your `main` function? Are you trying to put function calls outside of a function? You can't do that.

Comment: @tadman  thats because I am trying to figure something out about C++ and C

Comment: Does your actual code have `std::strcpy(x::s,"instance 1");` in the global space?

Comment: That's fine, but the question is what? It seems like you're trying to do three different things here at once and none of them is quite working.

Comment: @DarkFalcon answered it. I overlooked the fact that it had to be inside a main function. Got wrapped up in the other parts of the code and totally made a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the line

```
std::strcpy(x::s,"instance 1");
```

looks like a temporary variable the compiler, it tries to construct an instance of `std::strcpy` instead of calling the function.

At least this line must be inside a function body, e.g.

```
struct x {
    char a;
    static char s[20];
};

char x::s[20] = "instance 1";

int main(int, char **)
{
    std::strcpy(x::s,"instance 1");
}
```